# Unity3D C++ unmanaged DLL crash on windows 8/10, works on 7

Tags: c#, c++, windows, dll, unity-game-engine

I wrote a C++ unmanaged DLL for my Unity project using IDisposable inheritance  with HandleReference as described [here](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/) in the end.

The purpose is to load brain IRM with the C library [nifti2c](http://niftilib.sourceforge.net/), and meshes for creating realtime brain cuts which are converted later to GameObject and displayed in an Unity 3D scene.

All my C++ objects (volume,...) have an equivalent C# IDisposable class in order to be used with Unity C# scripting.

C++ Dll :

```
extern C
{
    Q_DECL_EXPORT hbp::Volume<float,float>* create_Volume(){return new hbp::Volume<float,float>();}
    Q_DECL_EXPORT void delete_Volume(hbp::Volume<float,float> *volume);
    Q_DECL_EXPORT void center_Volume(hbp::Volume<float,float> *volume, float *center);
    ...
}
```

Q_DECL_EXPORT is a Qt macro from QtGlobals

```
#  define Q_DECL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
```

C# script :

```
    public class Volume_dll : IDisposable 
    {
        [DllImport("hbp_export", EntryPoint = "create_Volume", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static private extern IntPtr create_Volume();  
        [DllImport("hbp_export", EntryPoint = "delete_Volume", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static private extern void delete_Volume(HandleRef handleVolume);
        [DllImport("hbp_export", EntryPoint = "center_Volume", 
    ...

    private HandleRef _handle;

    public Volume_dll()
    {
        _handle = new HandleRef(this, create_Volume());
    }

    ~Volume_dll()
    {
        Cleanup();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Cleanup();
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void Cleanup()
    {
        delete_Volume(_handle);
        _handle = new HandleRef(this, IntPtr.Zero);
    }

    public HandleRef getHandle()
    {
        return _handle;
    }

    public Vector3 center()
    {        
        float[] center = new float[3];
        center_Volume(_handle, center);
        return new Vector3(center[0],center[1],center[2]);
    }
   ...
}
```

I am currently using c++11 with VS2013 compiler with some others extern C++ libraries.

I use QtCreator for generating my Dll :

.pro :

```
TARGET = hbp_export
TEMPLATE = lib

############# CONFIG
CONFIG   += dll
CONFIG   -= app_bundle
CONFIG   += warn_on

QT += core gui widgets
CONFIG += opengl

############# DEFINES
DEFINES += _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

############# CFG
CFG = ""
CONFIG(debug, debug|release){
    CFG = "Debug"
}else{
    CFG = "Release"
}

############# ARCH
ARCH = ""
win32-msvc*:contains(QMAKE_TARGET.arch, x86_64):{
    ARCH = "x64"
}
win32-msvc*:contains(QMAKE_TARGET.arch, x86):{
    ARCH = "x86"
}

############# INCLUDEPATH
# hbp
HBP_DIR = "D:/_projects/HBP/HBP-*****/qt-creator/"
HBP_BASE_DIR = $$HBP_DIR"hbp_base/"
INCLUDEPATH += $$HBP_BASE_DIR"include"
INCLUDEPATH += $$HBP_BASE_DIR"include/niftilib"
INCLUDEPATH += $$HBP_BASE_DIR"gpc"
# boost
INCLUDEPATH += "D:/_software/boost_1_57_0/boost_1_57_0"
# opencv
INCLUDEPATH += "D:/_software/opencv/build/include"

############# LIBS
# opencv
CV_BASE = "D:/_software/opencv/build"

CV = "opencv_"
CV_VER = "2411"
equals(ARCH, "x86"){
    CV_BASE = $$CV_BASE"/x86/vc12"
}else{
    CV_BASE = $$CV_BASE"/x64/vc12"
}
CV_BIN = $$CV_BASE"/bin"
CV_LIB = $$CV_BASE"/lib"
CV_EXT = ""
equals(CFG, "Debug"){
    CV_EXT = "d"
}
LIBS += -L$$CV_BIN -L$$CV_LIB -l$$CV"imgproc"$$CV_VER$$CV_EXT -l$$CV"core"$$CV_VER$$CV_EXT# -l$$CV"highgui"$$CV_VER$$CV_EXT#
# hbp
OBJ_D = $$HBP_DIR"hbp_base_"
equals(ARCH, "x86"){
    OBJ_D = $$OBJ_D"x86/"
}else{
    OBJ_D = $$OBJ_D"x64/"
}
equals(CFG, "Debug"){
    OBJ_D = $$OBJ_D"debug/"
}else{
    OBJ_D = $$OBJ_D"release/"
}

LIBS += $$OBJ_D"nifti1_io.obj"  $$OBJ_D"Volume.obj"  ... \

SOURCES += \
    VolumeExport.cpp \
    ... \

HEADERS += \
    VolumeExport.h \
    ....h \
```

It works perfectly well on windows 7, i don't have any leaks and C++ objects destructors are called at the good time.
But it crashes on windows 8.1 and windows 10 a few moments after loading an IRM.

I made a C++ debug class for writing all functions calls in a txt file but when the crash occurs, nothing is written here.

The output log generated by the crash of the unity standalone build doesn't help that much :

```
========== OUTPUTING STACK TRACE ==================

0x00007FFEBA2E73C3 (hbp_export) delete_DebugSettings
0x00007FFEBA2BDC5F (hbp_export) center_Volume
0x00000000053A2B5E (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) Volume_dll:center_Volume (System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef,single[])
0x00000000053A29B3 (Mono JIT Code) [D:\_projects\HBP\HBP-flo\unity3D\testImportDll\Assets\Scripts\objects\Volume.cs:277] Volume_dll:center () 
0x00000000053A25CC (Mono JIT Code) [D:\_projects\HBP\HBP-flo\unity3D\testImportDll\Assets\Scripts\scenes\Base3DScene.cs:405] Base3DScene:resetNIIBrainVolumeFile (string) 
0x00000000053A1791 (Mono JIT Code) [D:\_projects\HBP\HBP-flo\unity3D\testImportDll\Assets\Scripts\scenes\SinglePatient3DScene.cs:106] SinglePatient3DScene:reset (string,System.Collections.Generic.List`1<string>,string,string,string,string) 
0x00000000053A16CC (Mono JIT Code) [D:\_projects\HBP\HBP-flo\unity3D\testImportDll\Assets\Scripts\scenes\ScenesManager.cs:53] ScenesManager:setSinglePatientPaths (string,System.Collections.Generic.List`1<string>,string,string,string,string) 
0x00000000053A12C8 (Mono JIT Code) [D:\_projects\HBP\HBP-flo\unity3D\testImportDll\Assets\Scripts\HBP_3D_Visu.cs:222] HBP_3D_Visu:testUi1 () 
0x00000000053A0F8D (Mono JIT Code) [D:\_projects\HBP\HBP-flo\unity3D\testImportDll\Assets\Scripts\HBP_3D_Visu.cs:168] HBP_3D_Visu:<Awake>m__0 () 
0x00000000053A0F3A (Mono JIT Code) [C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime\Export\UnityEvent.cs:149] UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall:Invoke (object[]) 
0x000000000533DEA5 (Mono JIT Code) [C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime\Export\UnityEvent.cs:626] UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCallList:Invoke (object[]) 
0x000000000533D784 (Mono JIT Code) [C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime\Export\UnityEvent.cs:766] UnityEngine.Events.UnityEventBase:Invoke (object[]) 
0x00000000053A0ED4 (Mono JIT Code) [C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime\Export\UnityEvent_0.cs:54] UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent:Invoke () 
0x00000000053A0E81 (Mono JIT Code) [C:\buildslave\unity\build\Extensions\guisystem\UnityEngine.UI\UI\Core\Button.cs:35] UnityEngine.UI.Button:Press () 
0x00000000053A0DE3 (Mono JIT Code) [C:\buildslave\unity\build\Extensions\guisystem\UnityEngine.UI\UI\Core\Button.cs:44] UnityEngine.UI.Button:OnPointerClick (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData) 
0x00000000053A0D88 (Mono JIT Code) [C:\buildslave\unity\build\Extensions\guisystem\UnityEngine.UI\EventSystem\ExecuteEvents.cs:52] UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:Execute (UnityEngine.EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler,UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData) 
0x000000000539BAC2 (Mono JIT Code) [C:\buildslave\unity\build\Extensions\guisystem\UnityEngine.UI\EventSystem\ExecuteEvents.cs:269] UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:Execute<object> (UnityEngine.GameObject,UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData,UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents/EventFunction`1<object>) 
0x000000000539A5DB (Mono JIT Code) [C:\buildslave\unity\build\Extensions\guisystem\UnityEngine.UI\EventSystem\InputModules\StandaloneInputModule.cs:378] UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessMousePress (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerInputModule/MouseButtonEventData) 
0x000000000539454C (Mono JIT Code) [C:\buildslave\unity\build\Extensions\guisystem\UnityEngine.UI\EventSystem\InputModules\StandaloneInputModule.cs:277] UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessMouseEvent (int) 
0x000000000539447F (Mono JIT Code) [C:\buildslave\unity\build\Extensions\guisystem\UnityEngine.UI\EventSystem\InputModules\StandaloneInputModule.cs:265] UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessMouseEvent () 
0x0000000005393B75 (Mono JIT Code) [C:\buildslave\unity\build\Extensions\guisystem\UnityEngine.UI\EventSystem\InputModules\StandaloneInputModule.cs:179] UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:Process () 
0x0000000005367DE1 (Mono JIT Code) [C:\buildslave\unity\build\Extensions\guisystem\UnityEngine.UI\EventSystem\EventSystem.cs:277] UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update () 
0x00000000053189AB (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) object:runtime_invoke_void__this__ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
0x00007FFEAB024087 (mono) mono_set_defaults
0x00007FFEAAF783DD (mono) mono_runtime_invoke
0x00007FF677A485C5 (hbp1) ScriptingInvocationNoArgs::Invoke
0x00007FF677A482D7 (hbp1) ScriptingInvocationNoArgs::Invoke
0x00007FF6779337E0 (hbp1) MonoBehaviour::CallMethodIfAvailable
0x00007FF67793632A (hbp1) MonoBehaviour::Update
0x00007FF67790117F (hbp1) BaseBehaviourManager::CommonUpdate<BehaviourManager>
0x00007FF6779F3F24 (hbp1) PlayerLoop
0x00007FF677B35820 (hbp1) PlayerMainWndProc
0x00007FF677B39463 (hbp1) PlayerWinMain
0x00007FF67803995C (hbp1) stricmp
0x00007FFED4EF2D92 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFED5FF9F64 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart

========== END OF STACKTRACE ===========
```

I'm okay with the fact that the crash occurs in center_Volume as written, but delete_DebugSettings is the last fucntion to be called in all my code !
So i modified my debug function for displaying each DLL function call in the console and we never see delete_DebugSettings.

[image]

The loading is a success and just after i can visualize all the data and compute the volume center.

I think the function center_volume tries to acess memory with a deleted pointer. The function above, convert_to_volume read the nii brain volume and stock the data as expected from my C# script :

```
public bool resetNIIBrainVolumeFile(string pathNIIBrainVolumeFile)
            {
                m_.isVolumeLoaded = false;    

                // checks parameter
                    if (pathNIIBrainVolumeFile.Length == 0)
                    {
                        Debug.LogError("-ERROR : Base3DScene::resetNIIBrainVolumeFile -> path NII brain volume file is empty. ");
                        return (m_.isSurfaceLoaded = false);
                    }

                // load volume
                    bool loadingSuccess = m_.DLLNiiLoader.loadNiftiFile(pathNIIBrainVolumeFile);
                    if (loadingSuccess)
                    {     
                        m_.DLLNiiLoader.convertToVolume(m_.DLLVolume);
                        // HERE the irm is loaded and i can call volume_center without any problem
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.LogError("-ERROR : Base3DScene::resetNIIBrainVolumeFile -> load NII file failed. " + pathNIIBrainVolumeFile);
                        return m_.isVolumeLoaded;                        
                    }

                    // set bbox and center
                    if (loadingSuccess)
                    {
                        // CRASH HERE when trying to access irm data !
                        m_.volumeCenter = m_.DLLVolume.center();   
                    }

                m_.isVolumeLoaded = loadingSuccess;
                updatePlanesEvent.Invoke(true);
                return m_.isVolumeLoaded;
            }
```

The details fo volume center :

```
void center_Volume(Volume<float,float> *volume, float *center)
{
    DebugSettings::displayDebug("(VolumeExport) center_Volume " + getHour() + "\n");
    if(volume == nullptr)
        return;

    Point3<float> centerSurface = volume->center(); // CRASH HERE
    center[0] = centerSurface.x();
    center[1] = centerSurface.y();
    center[2] = centerSurface.z();
    DebugSettings::displayDebug("      -> : " + to_string(centerSurface.x()) + " " + to_string(centerSurface.y()) + " " + to_string(centerSurface.z()) + "\n");
}

    template<class T1, class T2>
    Point3<T1> hbp::Volume<T1,T2>::center() const
    {
        Point3<T1> p1 = m_voxels[0].pos; // CRASH HERE, m_voxels is a vector of  
//points initialized once during the loading an never deleted
        Point3<T1> p2 = m_voxels[dimX() * dimY() * dimZ()-1].pos;
        return Point3<T1>((p1.x() + p2.x())/2, (p1.y() + p2.y())/2,(p1.z() +   p2.z())/2);
    }
```

I don't understand why the volume is deleted (or if the pointer is dereferenced) just after the loading of the data. There is only one process at this time and i use GC.SuppressFinalize(this) for disabling the garbage collector in the c# volume script.

As it doesn't make sens for me, i think more about a DLL incompability between windows 7 and windows 8/10.
For now i'm out of ideas, thanks for any advice.

Comment: Likely this is a simple use-after-free. The heap becomes more strict with later Windows, so use-after-free is more likely to cause a crash.

Comment: I agree with that, but none of my destructor are called and none of my pointer is dereferenced. And i always set my pointers to nullptr after a delete in the DLL.

Comment: Have you tried running it in the debugger?

Comment: I can't do that for the moment, my configuration is only installed on a windows 7 computer and i don't have a full access to w8/10 computers i can only provide new dll's and C# code.

Comment: What's your declaration for `[DllImport("hbp_export", EntryPoint = "center_Volume", `    Most of it is missing?

Comment: Here it is :
    `[DllImport("hbp_export", EntryPoint = "center_Volume", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    static private extern void center_Volume(HandleRef handleVolume, float[] center);`

Comment: You may be seeing duplicate comdat folding (i.e. if more than one function generates identical machine code, they are folded into one). This may mean you get an inappropriate name on the call stack. So it is possible that the top function is not delete_DebugSettings at all. Also optimised code may obscure the call stack... Try with all optimisations turned off and see if you get better call stack data.

Comment: I put QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE to /Od instead of /O2, and the call  stack seems to be more obsure, in the order : split2_Surface (which is never called in this part), delete_DebugSettings (again), and center_volume.

Comment: I will investigate the nifti_lib tomorrow, maybe my misuse of low level C I/O function is the source of the use-after-free, it's an old lib and i had to use the flag _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS to remove some warnings inside. Thank for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem by removing the Volume constructor calls from the DLL when i tried to read an IRM, now i use always the same object with a clean function when necessary. I am not sure why but it seems that the IDisposable pattern doesn't work well when we derefence pointers in DLL.